# Multiple rows where only one field is different, how do i get rid of the rest of the data in the rows

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am trying to create a dataset to use in SSRS so that I can get an accurate reading of throughput per hour. The problem I encountered is that I have rows where all the data is the same except for one column and I'm not sure how to get rid of the rest of the data so that when I sum the fields the numbers do not blow up. Would I need to create CASE statements to replace the data with 0?

```
DECLARE @Weeks table (weeknumber int, mindateid int, maxdateid int, dateformatted date)
INSERT INTO @Weeks (weeknumber, mindateid, maxdateid, dateformatted)
select WeekNumber, MIN(DATEID), MAX(DATEID), MAX(CalendarDate)from dimDate
where IsCurrentMonth = 1
group by WeekNumber

SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(D.dateformatted,5) as dateformatted, weeknumber, 


/*SUM(ActualFootageAllocated) AS THROUGHPUT, 
SUM(SpoilageUnits), 
SUM(SpoilageCost), 
SUM(J.ActualLaborMinutes / 60) AS LaborHours*/

S.JobID,
ActualFootageAllocated AS THROUGHPUT, 
SpoilageUnits, 
SpoilageCost, 
J.ActualLaborMinutes / 60 AS LaborHours


FROM factSpoilage S
JOIN factJobLabor J on S.JobID = J.JobID
JOIN dimCostCenter C on S.Press = C.CostCenterMajor
JOIN @Weeks D ON S.JobDateID between D.mindateid and D.maxdateid
WHERE S.EmployeeID = 9--@EmployeeEmployeeName
AND C.CostCenterMajor not like '%.%'

group by dateformatted, weeknumber, s.JobID, ActualFootageAllocated, SpoilageUnits, SpoilageCost, J.ActualLaborMinutes 
ORDER BY 1





/*UNION ALL
SELECT RIGHT(dateformatted,5) as dateformatted, 0,0,0,0 from @Weeks where RIGHT(dateformatted,5) not in (
SELECT RIGHT(D.dateformatted,5) as dateformatted 
FROM factSpoilage S
JOIN dimCostCenter C on S.Press = C.CostCenterMajor
JOIN @Weeks D ON S.JobDateID between D.mindateid and D.maxdateid
WHERE S.EmployeeID = @EmployeeEmployeeName
AND C.CostCenterMajor not like '%.%'

group by dateformatted)
order by 1*/
```

CURRENT OUTPUT W/O SUM BUT REPEATED ROW DATA

```
dateformatted   weeknumber  JobID   THROUGHPUT  SpoilageUnits   SpoilageCost    LaborHours
12-06             201448    21761   12100           734          30.75          2.0000000
12-06             201448    21761   26875           1576         66.03          0.0000000
12-06             201448    21761   26875           1576         66.03          1.0000000
12-06             201448    21762   3800            134          5.61           0.0000000
12-06             201448    21762   3800            134          5.61           1.0000000
```

DESIRED OUTPUT

```
dateformatted   weeknumber  JobID   THROUGHPUT  SpoilageUnits   SpoilageCost    LaborHours
12-06            201448      21761  12100           734            30.75         2.0000000
12-06            201448      21761  26875           1576           66.03         0.0000000
12-06            201448      21761  0               0                  0         1.0000000
12-06            201448      21762  3800            134             5.61         0.0000000
12-06            201448      21762  0               0                  0         1.0000000
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Comment: Depends what you mean by "get rid of data".. can you show your current output and your desired output?

Comment: @TabAlleman  included in original statement

Comment: It's possible to get your desired results, but it's a weird thing to want.   What if you filtered out rows where LaborHours=0?  or if you summed the LaborHours for each JobID?  I would think the results you're after would be confusing to the report consumers.

Comment: My end goal is to get laborhours/throughput so that I can get feet per hour to use in an ssrs dashboard. I could filter out laborhours=0 but there are rows where there are laborhours and repeat data. I gave a bad example sorry. And if sum by jobid wouldn't that still pull in the repeat data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to preserve rows with zeros in them as opposed to just typical grouping and using a sum aggregation on Labor Hours.  But, this is how I would do it.

```
-------------------------
-- MOCK SCHEMA 
-------------------------
DECLARE @UserData AS TABLE
    (dateformatted varchar(5), weeknumber int, JobID int, THROUGHPUT int, SpoilageUnits int, SpoilageCost numeric, LaborHours int)
;

INSERT INTO @UserData
    (dateformatted, weeknumber, JobID, THROUGHPUT, SpoilageUnits, SpoilageCost, LaborHours)
VALUES
    ('12-06', 201448, 21761, 12100, 734, 30.75, 2.0000000),
    ('12-06', 201448, 21761, 26875, 1576, 66.03, 0.0000000),
    ('12-06', 201448, 21761, 26875, 1576, 66.03, 1.0000000),
    ('12-06', 201448, 21762, 3800, 134, 5.61, 0.0000000),
    ('12-06', 201448, 21762, 3800, 134, 5.61, 1.0000000)
;

-------------------------
-- QUERY
-------------------------
WITH numberedSet AS
(
    SELECT 
        dateformatted
        , weeknumber
        , JobID
        , THROUGHPUT
        , SpoilageUnits  
        , SpoilageCost  
        , LaborHours
        , ROW_NUMBER() over ( PARTITION BY dateformatted, weeknumber, JobID, THROUGHPUT, SpoilageUnits, SpoilageCost ORDER BY dateformatted) as rownumber
    FROM
        @UserData
)

SELECT
    dateformatted
    , weeknumber
    , JobID
    , CASE rownumber WHEN 1 THEN THROUGHPUT ELSE 0 END AS THROUGHPUT
    , CASE rownumber WHEN 1 THEN SpoilageUnits ELSE 0 END AS SpoilageUnits  
    , CASE rownumber WHEN 1 THEN SpoilageCost ELSE 0 END AS SpoilageCost  
    , LaborHours
    , rownumber
FROM
    numberedSet
```